# Populate JList with unique elements

Tags: netbeans-8

I have a string vector and some elements repeat in it.
Now I want to insert this data into a Java swing JList, but I want all the list items to be unique. How can I do this??

Comment: Do you want your JList to have duplicate values?

Comment: No. I only want the unique values in the vector.